# Attaching an AWS VPC to an IGW with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to build a VPC resource with Terraform to provide for an MWAA build.  In the AWS documentation, I see the below resources (in addition to subnets, etc.) are defined to create a whole VPC environment.  I have defined `aws_vpc` & `aws_internet_gateway` with Terraform, but cannot find a Terraform template for `InternetGatewayAttachment` - ***only*** for `aws_vpn_gateway_attachment`.

1. **How do I go about attaching the VPC resource to the IGW w/Terraform?**
2. **Do I need an  resource, or is that implied w/the vpc_id in the TF aws_internet_gateway resource definition?**

P. S. - I am coming from GCP & not *super* familiar w/AWS Networking concepts.

```
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

....
```

Comment: Why are you including a CloudFormation template in a question about Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Create VPC

2 Create an Internet Gateway

> resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
> cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"}

> resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
> vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}

in the internet gateway you can give the name of the vpc.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway) you will see that the Internet Gateway resource requires you to specify the VPC ID. Terraform doesn't support creating internet gateways without immediately attaching them to a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about attaching the VPC resource to the IGW w/Terraform?

You've got two options - one is what [X-Men's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67424966/14367790) shows, i.e. using a `aws_vpc` and a `aws_internet_gateway`.

There's another option to attach later using a separate [`aws_internet_gateway_attachment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway_attachment) resource.

> Do I need an resource, or is that implied w/the vpc_id in the TF aws_internet_gateway resource definition?

You don't need a resource, it's implied from the `vpc_id` on the internet gateway, but a resource would be helpful if you want to defer attachment until later.

Be sure you don't define both a [`vpc_id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway#vpc_id) in the `aws_internet_gateway` and a `aws_internet_gateway_attachment` - this cause Terraform to try to double-attach and result in an error like this, which I've just had and found this question(!) (IDs removed):

*Internet Gateway ... Resource.AlreadyAssociated ... already attached to network*