# How to attach IGW to VPC using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

There are two options provided by terraform to attach IGW to VPC one is `aws_internet_gateway` and other one is `aws_internet_gateway_attachment`. Exactly what is the difference between both of these methods ?

[checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73812176/14580983) this as well but couldn't figure out the exact difference and usage of both ways

Comment: `aws_internet_gateway` manages the IGW and `aws_internet_gateway_attachment` manages the attachment.

Comment: do we need both to attach IGW to VPC

Comment: That would depend on whether the IGW already exists outside of Terraform managed infra or not.

Comment: can you explain a bit further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/internet_gateway) for `aws_internet_gateway` you will see you can attach it to a VPC directly via the `vpc_id` argument. The documentation for the `vpc_id` argument states:

> (Optional) The VPC ID to create in. See the aws_internet_gateway_attachment resource for an alternate way to attach an Internet Gateway to a VPC.

If you are creating the Internet Gateway, then you have to use the `aws_internet_gateway` resource to create it. While you are creating it there is really no reason to not go ahead and attach it to the VPC at that point using the `vpc_id` attribute.

If, for some reason you were not creating the Internet Gateway in Terraform, you would look it up via the Internet Gateway [datasource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/internet_gateway), and then attach it to the VPC with the `aws_internet_gateway_attachment` resource.

There may also be issues with certain VPC configurations in Terraform that create a circular reference between the VPC and the Internet Gateway, in which case splitting up the association into a separate `aws_internet_gateway_attachment` resource would fix the circular reference.

---

In general, you will almost always just use `aws_internet_gateway` and specify a `vpc_id`. If for some reason you are running into an issue in the structure of your Terraform code, either because you are getting a circular reference error, or because you are creating the VPC and the Internet Gateway in different Terraform modules or something, then you would use the additional `aws_internet_gateway_attachment` resource.